# catching ProcessTimedOutException in Laravel's artisan queue:listen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, amazon-sqs

We have a bunch of SQS jobs that we watch for and process using Laravel's `php artisan queue:listen`.

Periodically, has a few minutes' blip and SQS times out. When this happens, `queue:listen` aborts with a message like:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]                                                                                             
  The process "php artisan queue:work
    --queue="https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/*******/queue"
    --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 -env=production"
  exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.
```

I've tried handling the exception in `app/start/global.php` and alternatively `app/start/artisan.php`:

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException $exception) {
    // do nothing
});
```

Unfortunately, the exception still occurs and my `queue:listen` still dies.

How can I catch this exception and ignore it for a retry?

Comment: Your "do nothing" exception handler must return something, else the default handler will be called.  See [`Illuminate\Exception\Handler::handleException()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php#L143)

Comment: However, even if you return something and therefore avoid the default handler, the listener will still abort after the exception is raised.  I don't think this behaviour can be changed.  Why not increase the timeout, or set it to `null` for unlimited?

Comment: @eggyal I could swear we handle some exceptions with `App::error` in a manner that allows continued execution. I'll have to check. Increasing the timeout isn't feasible - if SQS never responds I can't exactly let the thing run forever.

Comment: You may be right.  I'm familiar with neither Symfony nor Laravel - that's just my take from [reading the sources](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L125), although I'll readily admit that I may have misunderstood the exception handling process.

Comment: @ceejayoz You cannot. You can let an error handler fall through to the next one, but at the end an `App::error` handler is called due to an uncaught exception which will cause your application to terminate regardless.

Comment: Wondering whether you got this solved now. Running against the same issues with a timeout on the beanstalkd listener.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I use SupervisorD for running crons and I have that fire off a queue:work every second, I don't have any issues with SQS then.

Answer (score 0):

You have either re-run "php artisan queue:work ..." queue job in your exception handler,

or increase /vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process::setTimeout() value to something higher.

Or maybe both.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more like workaround:

Whenever I need to make sure that process will run even error occurs I am using [npms forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). This handy tool will restart process as soon as it crashes.

Installation is pretty straight forward:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
sudo npm -g install forever
```

Use this command to start process: `forever start -c php artisan queue:listen`
If You need to stop it: `forever stopall`

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts will happen from time to time.  The Symfony Process class has its own timeout settings that are causing this particular timeout (I believe).  I'm not sure that you can catch this without editing core Laravel code pertaining to the worker, which is not a good idea.

I would strongly suggest using supervisor as shown in the Laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration

This will automatically reboot your listener even if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related queue job running time, As I know, default running time 30 seconds, you should increase this value, you can increase two way,

`php artisan queue:listen --timeout=1200`

or you can set `$timeout` for specific job

```
 /**
 * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $timeout = 1200;
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Ultimately, that's just a band-aid on the issue - it'll make a crash less likely, but if it hits 1200 seconds `queue:listen` will still die. The workaround I've wound up using is Laravel Horizon and its supervisor setup.

Comment: Did you try this with `php artisan queue:work --timeout=1200` ? and you are getting error after 1200 seconds ?

Comment: Again, extending the timeout is just lengthening the time it takes for a process to throw a `ProcessTimedOutException`. A job that takes 1,201 seconds would error out. (I also wouldn't **want** most of my queued jobs to be allowed to run that long. The goal here is to have jobs time out in a *reasonable* length of time **and** not crash the `queue:listen` process if they get stuck.)

Comment: i see, I think for solution, You should define `public $timeout = xxxx;` as needed time for specific jobs to finish.

Comment: Still missing the point. Timeouts crash the `queue:listen` process. I wanted to let it timeout **and** keep the `queue:listen` process active to continue processing other jobs, instead of crashing because of the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


abstract class Job implements ShouldQueue, JobStatusInterface
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 1; // try only once

    public function handle()
    {

    }
}
```

use this abstract class
and dispatch it the extended class it solve your problem

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Job;
use Log;
use Exception;
/**
 * Class CheckStockJob
 */
 class CheckStockJob extends Job
 {
     public $tries = 100; // how many you need to retry
     public function handle()
     {
        try {
          // do something here
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
          Log::error($e);
          throw $e; // rethrow to make job fail
        }
     }
 }
```

somewhere in your code

```
$t = new CheckStockJob();
dispatch($t);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to investigate available parameters of the command by executing:

`php artisan queue:listen --help`.

You can pass timeout value in seconds, the number of tries etc.